# Loop in Python script

Tags: python, loops

I writed a simple calculator and have little problem.
When I input 'dodawanie' then i can input another two numbers and almost everything is working fine but then i cannot use 'dodawanie' sequence again only next sequence which is 'odejmowanie', after use last sequence i was not able to use anything and script ends.

```
wpisane = input('>') #<<<

#dodawanie
if wpisane == dodawanie:    
    pierwsza = input('Podaj pierwsza liczbe: ')
    druga = input('Podaj druga liczbe: ')   
    wynik_dodawania = (int(pierwsza) + int(druga));
    plus = '+'
    równa_się = '='
    print()
    print(int(pierwsza), plus, int(druga), równa_się, wynik_dodawania);
    print()
    wpisane=input('>')


#odejmowanie
if wpisane == odejmowanie:
    pierwsza = input('Podaj pierwsza liczbe: ')
    druga = input('Podaj druga liczbe: ')   
    wynik_odejmowania = (int(pierwsza) - int(druga));
    minus = '-'
    równa_się = '='
    print()
    print(int(pierwsza), minus, int(druga), równa_się, wynik_odejmowania);
    print()
    wpisane = input('>')
```

So i decided to def the 'wpisane = input('>') and make somehow loop

```
def komenda():
    wpisane = input('>')

komenda()

#dodawanie
if wpisane == dodawanie:    
    pierwsza = input('Podaj pierwsza liczbe: ')
    druga = input('Podaj druga liczbe: ')   
    wynik_dodawania = (int(pierwsza) + int(druga));
    plus = '+'
    równa_się = '='
    print()
    print(int(pierwsza), plus, int(druga), równa_się, wynik_dodawania);
    print()
    komenda()


#odejmowanie
if wpisane == odejmowanie:
    pierwsza = input('Podaj pierwsza liczbe: ')
    druga = input('Podaj druga liczbe: ')   
    wynik_odejmowania = (int(pierwsza) - int(druga));
    minus = '-'
    równa_się = '='
    print()
    print(int(pierwsza), minus, int(druga), równa_się, wynik_odejmowania);
    print()
    komenda()
```

and then get 'name "wpisane" is not defined' so i def it

```
def komenda():
    wpisane = input('>')
    def wpisane():
        komenda()
```

and at the end script do only 'Press any key to continue' :(
Where I'm making mistake? Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm understanding the question, put all your code in a infinite loop:

```
while True:
    wpisane = input('>')

    #dodawanie
    if wpisane == dodawanie:    
        pierwsza = input('Podaj pierwsza liczbe: ')
        druga = input('Podaj druga liczbe: ')   
        wynik_dodawania = (int(pierwsza) + int(druga));
        plus = '+'
        równa_się = '='
        print()
        print(int(pierwsza), plus, int(druga), równa_się, wynik_dodawania);
        print()


    #odejmowanie
    if wpisane == odejmowanie:
        pierwsza = input('Podaj pierwsza liczbe: ')
        druga = input('Podaj druga liczbe: ')   
        wynik_odejmowania = (int(pierwsza) - int(druga));
        minus = '-'
        równa_się = '='
        print()
        print(int(pierwsza), minus, int(druga), równa_się, wynik_odejmowania);
        print()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There is no loop in your code.

In order to query the user for input over and over again, use something like this:

```
def do_the_calculations(user_input):
    if user_input == 'option_one':
        pierwsza = input('Podaj pierwsza liczbe: ')
        [...]

    elif user_input == 'option_two':
        pierwsza = input('Podaj pierwsza liczbe: ')
        [...]

while True:
    i = input('>')
    if i in ['q', 'quit', 'exit']:
        break
    do_the_calculations(i)
```